# LWC using NavigationMixin from creating new records from Screen Flow and screen not showing up

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

I have a lightning component that is using the NavigationMixin to create a new record from a **screen flow**. Below is how the component looks.

[image]

When a I select "New Account" from the screenflow, the NavigationMixin does not fire anything.

**lookupComonent.js**

```
handleNewRecordClick(event) {
    const objectApiName = event.currentTarget.dataset.sobject;
    const selection = this.newRecordOptions.find((option) => option.value === objectApiName);

    const preNavigateCallback = selection.preNavigateCallback
        ? selection.preNavigateCallback
        : () => Promise.resolve();
    preNavigateCallback(selection).then(() => {
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'standard__objectPage',
            attributes: {
                objectApiName,
                actionName: 'new'
            },
            state: {
                defaultFieldValues: selection.defaults
            }
        });
    });
```

Is there a workaround for creating records from screen flows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed the attributename called [objectApiName](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/reference_page_reference_type) in your code:-

```
    this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
        type: 'standard__objectPage',
        attributes: {
            objectApiName : objectApiName,
            actionName: 'new'
        },
        state: {
            defaultFieldValues: selection.defaults
        }
    });
```

Also, Check this [LWC - NavigationMixin From Flow](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/377338/lwc-navigationmixin-from-flow)

I have a working example here - https://salesforcediaries.com/2022/01/06/lwc-inside-flow-with-custom-footer/